# How to display API Information to ReactDOM?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-dom

Currently Im fetching stock data, from yahoo finance in Rapid API. I am able to log the 'bid' of the stock to the console and any information to the console. However I cannot seem to find a solution on how to actually show it in the browser on a simple webpage.

Heres what I have so far

```
import React from "react";



const Test = () => {



fetch("https://yh-finance.p.rapidapi.com/market/v2/get-quotes?region=US&symbols=VTI%2C%20AAPL%2CTSLA%2CFB", {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "yh-finance.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "api-key"
    }
})
.then(res => res.json())

.then(res => {
    console.log(res.quoteResponse.result[3].bid)
})



    return (
        <>
        <h1>{}</h1>
        </>
    )
}



export default Test
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to manage [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html) which stores your api response and [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to better manage the api calls. read the docs for context api.

in the mean time below solution should work

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";



const Test = () => {
const [apiResponse, setApiResponse] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
  fetch("https://yh-finance.p.rapidapi.com/market/v2/get-quotes?region=US&symbols=VTI%2C%20AAPL%2CTSLA%2CFB", {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "yh-finance.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "api-key"
    }
})
.then(res => setApiResponse(res.json()))

.then(res => {
    console.log(res.quoteResponse.result[3].bid)
})
},[])




    return (
        <>
        <h1>{apiResponse}</h1>
        </>
    )
}



export default Test
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the reply and your insight :)! It unfortnuelty kicked back an error and said "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: Maybe is should destructor ?

Comment: oh forgot about converting the json response to string in h1. change `<h1>{apiResponse}</h1>` to `<h1>{JSON.stringify(apiResponse)}</h1>`